# Using trigger to implement UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, cascade, updating

So I have this particular attribute (`Sportcode`) I am asked to implement update cascade by writing a trigger. this particular attribute is in the table below:

Sports

```
Sportcode       sport name                     sport event no
--------------- ------------------------------ ---------------
AR              Archery                               2 
AT              Athletics                             3 
BD              Badminton                             4 
BK              Basketball                            6 
BS              Baseball                              5 
BV              Beach Volleyball                     26
```

How do I use a trigger to implement update cascade for `Sportcode`?

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure whether this is what i am supposed to do but i came up with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Sportcode_Upd_Cas
  BEFORE UPDATE OF Sportcode ON sports
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE sports
    SET Sportcode =:new.Sportcode
    WHERE Sportcode =:old.Sportcode;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Corresponding Sportcode in the Sports table has also been updated');
END;
```

Comment: Do you mean, update values of discipline code in a child table whenever they are updated in the parent table?

Comment: Please edit this post and add the definition of the table, including primary and foreign keys.  Thanks.

Comment: @PriscillaChen, you seem to be trying to update `DISCIPLINE` with a trigger on `DISCIPLINE` ... that won't do. Please see @njk's answer below -- it can be applied to any parent/child tables.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm) manual, you would do something like this to accomplish an `UPDATE CASCADE` effect without providing us the referencing keys:

```
create table p (p1 number constraint ppk primary key); 
create table f (f1 number constraint ffk references p); 
create trigger pt after update on p for each row begin
  update f set f1 = :new.p1 where f1 = :old.p1;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `DISCIPLINE` is the parent table and `DISCIPLINE_CHILD` is the child table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER discipline_code_update
 AFTER UPDATE OF discipline_code ON discipline FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE discipline_child
       SET discipline_code = :new.discipline_code
     WHERE discipline_code = :old.discipline_code;
END;
/
```

I included the `OF discipline_code` so that the trigger does not fire if `discipline_code` is not included in the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If DISCIPLINE_CODE is the primary key on your table, you REALLY should not be changing it.  Please recall that a primary key has three attributes:

1. It is NOT NULL
2. It is UNIQUE, and
3. IT IS NEVER CHANGED.

The reason for #3 is exactly what you're encountering now - if you change the primary key then all existing references to that row throughout the database also need to be changed.  This is why primary keys should never be changed.

Oracle will enforce the first two, but no database I've encountered enforces #3.  If you're changing DISCIPLINE_CODE on this table then by definition it's NOT REALLY A PRIMARY KEY, and while you can write code which will do that it's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

A pitfall to implementing UPDATE CASCADE is another reason besides the ones @bob-jarvis mentioned. You have to be careful with multi-row updates. If it is possible that values may be reused, causing the AFTER value of one record to overlap with the BEFORE of another, the result is child rows updating multiple times and migrating to a different parent.

Example:

Parent

```
1
2
```

Child

```
1
2
```

After running:

```
update parent set id = id + 1
```

you get:

Parent

```
2
3
```

Child

```
3
3
```

Either don't reuse key values, or implement logic not to update the same row twice in the trigger, or better yet, don't use this approach at all and use truly IMMUTABLE primary keys.